# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined for input fields

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var username = 'xyz';
var password = 'xyz';
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP');
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('sqdOP L3NKy y3zKF');
input[0].value = username;
input[1].value = password;
button.click();
```

Every time I get this error, but in the console, the two input fields are found in the dom.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

I'm able to get the HTML collection array of the two elements.

This is the outerHTML of them:

```
<input aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="password" type="password" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value=""> 

<input aria-label="Numero di telefono, nome utente o e-mail" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">"
```

Here is a screen of the consolle
[image: consolle screen]

Any solution?

Comment: Please post your html, your selector probably hasn't found the input element.

Comment: Depending on the line the error occurs, `input` contains only zero or one element.

Comment: Wait! If you can get the values in the console, then you're executing the script before those elements exist. Put your code to the bottom of the body.

Comment: @Addis I have two input fields with the same class, if I log the input var it will return me the two elements

Comment: @Teemu I'm injecting the script inside an electron based app so I don't have the ability to choiche were to put it

Comment: Then you've to wrap the code in `load` or `DOMContenLoaded` handler, if you can't control the placement.

Comment: `document.addEventListener`  will work ?

Comment: For the latter, yes, for load you use `window`.

Comment: I'm reading the [docs](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject), the code is injected after the dom has loaded

Comment: Then it should work as it is, unless you're dynamically create the elements after injecting yhe script.

Comment: I think the elements are created using angular, react or similar. Can be this a problem and is there a solution? The app that I need to modify is the login form of instagram wrapped inside a macOS app

Answer (score 2):

A class name cannot contain spaces. If you are looking for elements with each of those space-separated classes, use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName`:

```
const input = document.querySelectorAll('._2hvTZ.pexuQ.zyHYP');
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF');
```

As mentioned before, since `button` will be an array-like `NodeList`, which has no `click()` method.

Here's an example with the HTML you added in the comments:

```js
const input = document.querySelectorAll('._2hvTZ.pexuQ.zyHYP');

console.log(input.length); // let's see how many there are
input[0].value = "I'm here";
input[1].value = "and here";
```

```html
<input aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="password" type="password" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">
<input aria-label="Numero di telefono, nome utente o e-mail" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the actual HTML of an element you wish to select.

Comment: Didn't work if I use the querySelectorAll, it will return an empty array of nodes.

Comment: As long as you don't show the outerHTML of the element you want to find, noone can help you.

Comment: Do you want all elements which have **either**  of the space-separated class names, or those that have **all** of the class names? My example code was based on the assumption of the latter.

Comment: this is the outerHtml of the password field `<input aria-label="Password" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="password" type="password" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">` 
This instead the outerHtml of the username field: `<input aria-label="Numero di telefono, nome utente o e-mail" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">"
`

Comment: I want all the two fields and set the value. The strange thing I'm noticing is that if I try to get the first element of the HTML collection using `input[0]` I get undefined in consolle

Comment: Are you sure your script waits until the DOM has been parsed, and the elements are available? Wait until you can see the elements, open developer tools of your browser, switch to console and type `document.querySelectorAll('._2hvTZ.pexuQ.zyHYP')[1].getAttribute('aria-label')`. What are you getting?

Comment: It will print the "Password" word that is the attribute of the field !

Comment: Then your problem is that at the time of execution of your code, the elements are not yet in the DOM. I guess the only way to have your code wait until those elements are available is setting up a mutation observer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver Though the proper way to do it would be to integrate your needs right into your Angular application. Stackoverflow won't get you any further at this point.

Comment: I never used the mutation observer, a little example will be helpful. Anyway I can only inject code into the app, not modify the source directly

Comment: You can find an example on MDN. Adjust to your needs, it's quite easy despite the complicated-sounding term.

Comment: It's basically like an event listener. Except the event is a change in the DOM, like the addition or removal of nodes.

Answer (score -1):

For this I would think you would want to access the fields by id, not class. that's not good programming, what you have.

also, you should always check if your array contains at least 2 elements before trying to access the second element of it.

one more thing... isn't "button" an array? (which is a bad name for an array) not sure if button.click() makes any sense.

Comment: The inputs field didn't have an id and I can't modify them because I don't have the source html code. The button element is selected and is an array with the only button found with that class

Comment: HTMLCollection, not array. Slight difference

Comment: No. Empty HTMLCollection